# Using variables in a SQL query which change for each returned record

Tags: sql-server

To begin - I am new at SQL; be gentle.

I work with a school district and have recently been given "the keys" to access the database.  I am interested in getting a list of students, and then generating a list of passwords for them.  I have found some code which allows me to generate random passwords that I would like to incorporate into a SQL query which is gathering information from our Student database. (Thank you if this code is yours!)

My issue is that I have not been able to use the variables to create a different password for each record.  I get the same randomly generated password for each student. (On a good note; at least the password changes each time I execute the query.)

I should mention that I have two accounts set up for the database access; one to simply read the information, and another with full editing rights.  (I have only used this once and closed my eyes as I pushed the big red button to update some trivial information).

Results from the first run:

```
Name    Password
JACEK   mtwsz2ybu      
CARL    mtwsz2ybu      
LARS    mtwsz2ybu
```

Results from the second run:

```
Name    Password
JACEK   je4tm5ptw      
CARL    je4tm5ptw      
LARS    je4tm5ptw
```

This is the query I am running:

```
USE XXTableXX
DECLARE @position int, @string char(100), @length int, 
@rand int, @newstring char(15), @newchar char(15);
SET @position = 1;
SET @string = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
SET @length = 9;
SET @newstring = ''
SET @newchar = ''
WHILE @position <= @length
BEGIN
SET @rand = FLOOR(RAND()*(33-1)+1);
SET @newchar = SUBSTRING(@string,@rand,1);
SET @newstring = STUFF(@newstring,len(@newstring)+1,1,@newchar)
SET @position = @position +1;
END;

SELECT DISTINCT s.firstname, @newstring AS [Password]
FROM XXStudentTableXX s
```

Comment: Honestly you don't want to do this. You should never store passwords in clear text. They should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the stuff above the query in a function and call the function in your query.  A side note, it will execute for each row, which means a bit of a performance hit for large sets.

Here is a way to do this.

First, you will need to make the RAND() into it's own view since you can't call it from a function

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[NewRandom]
AS
SELECT RAND() AS [RandSeed]
GO
```

Now you must create your function that uses the view.  This function accepts an integer so you can do variable password lengths.  You can hardcode it in your query or take out the parameter and hard code it in the function.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GeneratePassword] ( @PasswordLength INT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN


 DECLARE @position int, @string char(100), @length int, 
    @rand int, @newstring char(15), @newchar char(15);
    SET @position = 1;
    SET @string = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
    SET @length = @PasswordLength;
    SET @newstring = ''
    SET @newchar = ''
    WHILE @position <= @length
    BEGIN
    SET @rand = FLOOR((SELECT RandSeed FROM dbo.[NewRandom])*(33-1)+1);
    SET @newchar = SUBSTRING(@string,@rand,1);
    SET @newstring = STUFF(@newstring,len(@newstring)+1,1,@newchar)
    SET @position = @position +1;
    END

    RETURN @newstring

END
```

Now you can call the function on every row of your table

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.firstname, [dbo].[ufn_GeneratePassword](9)  AS [Password]
FROM XXStudentTableXX s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need to do for this is create a table, or table variable, then instead of selecting make it insert into the table. Also Add a loop that loops 1x for each student ID. This will then insert 1 row for each student and run the randomizer 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

First covert your procedure into a scalar SQL function.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.RandomNumberView 
AS
SELECT RandomNumber = RAND(); 
GO  


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GeneratePassword()
RETURNS char(15)
AS 
-- Generates and Returns a random password
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position int, @string char(100), @length int, 
    @rand int, @newstring char(15), @newchar char(15);
    SET @position = 1;
    SET @string = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
    SET @length = 9;
    SET @newstring = ''
    SET @newchar = ''
    WHILE @position <= @length
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rand = FLOOR(RandomNumber *(33-1)+1) FROM RandomNumberView;
        SET @newchar = SUBSTRING(@string,@rand,1);
        SET @newstring = STUFF(@newstring,len(@newstring)+1,1,@newchar)
        SET @position = @position +1;
    END;
    RETURN @newstring;
END;
GO
```

And then you can easily use it whatever way you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.firstname,     dbo.GeneratePassword() AS [Password]
FROM XXStudentTableXX s
```

Note that each time you run this query you would get different password against the same record. I would prefer to use this function to only generate and insert password in the table and not as a direct select statement.

Comment: Should I be able to do all of this in one query?  I tried, but I keep getting the error message:  "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GeneratePassword, Line 23 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."

Comment: I missed the fact that `RAND()` cannot be used inside a function due to its side-effecting behavior. @Tteeple 's solution is one workaround around this problem using a `VIEW`. His solution is same as mine with that workaround added. You may consider that solution.

Comment: Edited my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from a random table, SQL Server provides the NEWID () function. As its name says every execution is generated a new GUID (Global Unique Identifier), these GUIDs are unique, so the value of the order will never be the same.

Therefore you do not need to create a random function that does it for you. So you may have your answer using a simple SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    [ID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME]   NVARCHAR (100) NULL
);

INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME) VALUES ('Carl');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME) VALUES ('Mary');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME) VALUES ('Joan');

select
    ID
    ,NAME
    ,CONCAT(
      CAST((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10) as varchar(1))
      , CHAR(ASCII('a') + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25))
      , CHAR(ASCII('A') + (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 25))
      , LEFT(LOWER(NEWID()),2)
      , LEFT(NEWID(),2)
      , LEFT(LOWER(NEWID()),2)
    ) AS PASSWORD
from STUDENT
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bfa31/6)

However, you may wish to Make your own generator taking into account a high level of complexity generated password.

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/09/30/strong-password-generator/